# How to get all properties of a instance of a given class

Tags: sparql

Just started studying sparql and I'm not getting a single result back, no matter what syntax I try.

I've been told to, as the title say, get all properties of instances of a class inside http://dbpedia.org/ontology/

I've been trying several examples seen on this page and other tutorials, but either I get an error, for bad syntax most of the time, or I get results that do not show any relation with the class I'm trying to see its instances.

Example of queries I've tried:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?ind rdf:type ?type .
OPTIONAL { ?type rdfs:subClassOf ?Politician }
}
LIMIT 50
```

If we take this accepted answer in another thread:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
  ?entity rdf:type ?type.
  ?type rdfs:subClassOf* :C.
}
```

I fail to see what changes should I made to specify a particular class. Like, that doesn't work for me, it throws an error (`Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 6: Undefined namespace prefix at '' before '.' )`, but it's an accepted answer so what do I know.

I got somewhere closer with this adaptation of the previous query

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
  ?entity rdf:type ?type.
}
```

But, in this case, the problem is I get a whole lot of results that either don't make sense or I can't checker whether or not they are of instances of a certain class.

Same case with this one:

```
SELECT ?s ?politician WHERE  { ?s a ?politician }
```

I changed 1 single word and I'm getting so many results I don't understand where they come that it seems difficult to make such a simple thing.

Comment: Resource are identified by a URI, that means simply put the URI of the entity in subject position if you want to get information about it. `?politician` is just a variable (name), and does not lead to instances of type politician. Please try to read something about RDF first, then something about SPARQL - ideally, not questions and answers here, but a SPARQL tutorial.

Comment: I have read about RDF and done some exercises, and found no half decent SPARQL tutorial anywhere. Like I've seen the w3 official one and it didn't seem all that properly explained to someone with no previous background tbh. Any tutorial you know of?

Comment: Hm what about this one: http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example

Comment: That's the one I knew about but thanks regardless

Comment: Ok, you could start with an example query `SELECT * WHERE {<URI> ?p ?o .}` - this basically returns all (outgoing) facts for the entity identified by the given URI.

Comment: Roger that. Problem is, in a subject predicate object triplet, I fail to see how to query for instances. Like ok with your help I now have all facts for some URI. If that URI was a class, I see and get SOME of the things I see under the properties column of the URI. So, two questions, why aren't all "properties" listed, and second, as I said, how to make the jump to instances of that class. Again thanks for your help

Comment: Classes do not have properties connected to something, at least not the domain properties. In that case, you can get all instances of a class and for those instances the properties.

Comment: Seems like your instructor ought to be able to instruct...